# Sorting Program

Tags: c++, sorting, bubble-sort

I'm having the hardest time with this. I don't even understand the error messages anymore since there's so many of them. I think there's a problem with my alphaGreater() class function parameters but who knows. Can anybody get this to sort alphabetically using the bubble sort inside mySort()?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "phoneEntry.h"
using namespace std;

void mySort(PhoneEntry arr[], int size)
{
    bool inOrder = false;
    string temp;
    for (int i = size - 1; i > 0 && !inOrder; i--)
    {
        inOrder = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if(arr[j+1].alphaGreater(arr[j]))
            {
                inOrder = false;
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
};

int main()
{   
    const int MAXNUM = 500;
    PhoneEntry entry[MAXNUM];
    ifstream filezilla;
    filezilla.open("phone.txt");
    int count = 0;

    if(filezilla)
    {
        while(count < MAXNUM && entry[count].readEntry(filezilla))
        {
            count++;
            mySort(entry, count);
        }   

        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            entry[i].writeEntry(cout) << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "404" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Phone Entry Header](http://pastebin.com/f6Xvu398)

[Phone Number Header](http://pastebin.com/ytdi8x3D)

Sorting Text (http://pastebin.com/HE8Rsmbg)

My Errors...

```
>> g++ sort.cpp -o PhoneSort.exe
object.cpp: In function 'void mySort(PhoneEntry*, int)':
object.cpp:35:29: error: no match for 'operator=' in 'temp = *(arr + ((unsigned
int)(((unsigned int)j) * 20u)))'
object.cpp:35:29: note: candidates are:
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:541:7: not
e: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits
, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _C
harT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>, st
d::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> = std::basic_string<char>]
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:541:7: not
e:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'PhoneEntry' to 'const std::basic_s
tring<char>& {aka const std::basic_string<char>&}'
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:549:7: not
e: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits
, _Alloc>::operator=(const _CharT*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_tra
its<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Al
loc> = std::basic_string<char>]
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:549:7: not
e:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'PhoneEntry' to 'const char*'
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:560:7: not
e: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits
, _Alloc>::operator=(_CharT) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<cha
r>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> =
std::basic_string<char>]
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:560:7: not
e:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'PhoneEntry' to 'char'
object.cpp:37:30: error: no match for 'operator=' in '*(arr + ((((unsigned int)j
) + 1u) * 20u)) = temp'
object.cpp:37:30: note: candidate is:
phoneEntry.h:12:7: note: PhoneEntry& PhoneEntry::operator=(const PhoneEntry&)
phoneEntry.h:12:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::string
{aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'const PhoneEntry&'
```

Comment: Could you also post the errors? That'll help with figuring out what's wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No Match for Operator\[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384675/no-match-for-operator)

Comment: `temp = arr[j];` is trying to use `PhoneEntry::operator[]`, which doesn't exist, which is exactly what you were told in your last question.

Comment: I fixed that problem though by making it pass the entire array by reference

Comment: Now (post-edit) you're trying to assign a `PhoneEntry` to a `std::string`. How could that work?

Comment: I thought since the PhoneEntry is holding string values from the text file I can transport it into a string variable temporarily. Do I need to make that an object too and just pass the objects back and forth?

Comment: `PhoneEntry` _contains_ strings, but it _is not a_ string.

Comment: So no matter what an object contains it is still an object type?

Comment: Yes, of course; how would OOP be useful without the concept of object identity?

Comment: Why on earth would you write a bubble sort anyway? It's terrible, and has been well known to be for more than 30 years. If you want a bad (O(N**2) ) sort, use insertion sort or selection sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `arr` parameter holds an array of `PhoneEntry` values. You attempt to read an entry from that array and store it in a `string` when you write `temp = arr[j]`. You can't assign a `PhoneEntry` to a `string`. Change `temp` to have a type that can hold `PhoneEntry` values, namely `PhoneEntry`:

```
PhoneEntry temp = arr[j];
arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
arr[j + 1] = temp;
```

Better yet, use the `swap` function from the `<algorithm>` header. Remove the `temp` variable and replace the three lines above with this one:

```
std::swap(arr[j], arr[j + 1]);
```

Comment: Great it compiles! Now I just need to figure out why it is not sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
arr[j+1].alphaGreater(arr[j])
```

instead of

```
arr.alphaGreater(arr[j])
```

But I am guessing really.

Answer (score 0):

> object.cpp: In function 'void mySort(PhoneEntry*, int)':
>   object.cpp:35:29: error: no match for 'operator=' in 'temp = *(arr +
>   ((unsigned int)(((unsigned int)j) * 20u)))'

So, you're assigning a PhoneEntry to `temp`. `temp` is a std::string and PhoneEntry is not - hence the error.

Note that `temp` is only used in the innermost scope, so you should declare it there, and initialise it on the same line. (In general, you should not declare a local variable without initialising it.)

I would also suggest that you might have a look at the std::swap function.